# How to know where my MySQL database is being hosted and how can I access it?

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following information to a SQL database

> Server : MyUserName.mysql.db
>
> User : MyUserName
>
> Password : MyPassWord

I am a little noob in this context, so I have some questions:

- How to know where is hosted my database? Is it in mysql domain? (Isn't that the type of database?)
- How can I access it and visualize it?

Comment: Is this mysql or sql server? They are NOT the same thing.

Comment: Ask the person who gave you that info?

Comment: Not to sound sarcastic, but ask the DBA perhaps?

Comment: Sounds like you were given a user name, an account name. Assuming as an example that your user name is "joe", then I would expect that the database server can be accessed using the host name `joe.mysql.db` which _might_ make sense in a local environment. But it certainly does make sense to simply ask the person who gave you the information, as @ceejayoz suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, you need a CLIENT to be able to access your database. For MySQL, you can use either Workbench or MySQL CLIENT (the last giving you command-line level access).

Second, and according to your information, the server is `MyUserName.mysql.db` so if you try to PING that server you should get some response.

Third, MySQL has a default port number so you need to configure your client to access that server though that port (if I'm not mistaking, 3306).

You will also need access credentials to your database.

Your DB administrator should be able to provide all the information you need.

Comment: Also not really answering the question but offering some additional information which _might_ be useful.

Comment: @Joseph please explain me: (1) Where exactly I'm criticizing? (2) Why is my answer not an answer? Apparently, SO is also giving power to some that are not ready and mature enough to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Contact your database administrator.
If you're trying to acess/visualize sql server database on your local computer install ssms to connect to your local database , similarly you can access any other database through ssms.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer to the question. It should have been a comment maybe.

Comment: Yep, not an answer, flagging as such.

Comment: How can I access it and visualize it?

Comment: i just answered this.